# Is there a conditional statement in the python i2c library that can be used to assess whether or not a byte has been received in python?

Tags: python, i2c

I am using a raspberry pi and I wish to be able to receive numbers across an i2c bus. However the only problem is that I wish to transmit several numbers at regular intervals ,from the slave, and then assign them individual variables. I have a counter system in place that would increment a counter variable if a number had been received and reset when the six numbers that are being transmitted by the slave are received by the master. I am wondeing if there is a conditional statement within the python i2c library that I can use in conjunction with the bolean operator "if" to asses whether the number has been received and alow the counter variable to be incremented.

Comment: In general, the following I/O interfaces are common: (1) you call `read()` and it waits until data is available (blocking code -- that is how files work by default) (2) you call `read()` and it either returns the data immediately or reports that there is no data yet (non-blocking -- you could use `fcntl`, socket.settimeout(), etc, to enable non-blocking mode) (3) you pass a callback that is called once the data is available (asynchronous code -- `twisted`) (4) same as 3 but it looks like 1 in the code (`gevent`, `asyncio`).

Comment: So I could just have a loop containing the instruction to read the bus and then a counter that increments. Outside of the loop i could then have the variables to which each read byte will be assigned depending on its counter value. I could then have a peice of code that clears the variables when the counter reaches an arbitrary number. Does this sound ok?

Comment: It sounds more complicated then it should. You need to be more specific. If you want to read numbers then just read them. How to do it depends on the specific interface (how do you read the data) and the protocol you want to use (what is the specific format? Is it text/binary protocol?).